# UIPageViewController: child view controllers with different height

Tags: uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a **UIPageViewController** to display 3 different view controllers. The **UIPageViewController** is inside my hierarchy as follow:

- ScrollView

  - ContentView

    - UIImage
    - UILabel
    - UIPageViewController

I would like to add each child view controller of the UIPageViewController in a way that each extends into ScrollView based on its height. The child view controllers can contain different contents: a list of images, pre formatted text, just one image with a title and a description.

I'm having trouble to do that because for some reason I'm not able to calculate the exact height. 
My attempt was to change the height constraint on the ContentView every time I detect a swipe is completed.

This is how I add the page view controller:

```
self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
self.pageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view!)
self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

with the following constraints (using SnapKit):

```
self.pageViewController.view.snp.makeConstraints() { make in
    make.edges.equalToSuperview()
}
```

and every time I want to change the constraint constant I calculate the height of each view controller, iterating over the subviews and calculate the height amount.

Probably this is the wrong method wondering if someone have some hint.

Edit: https://imagebin.ca/v/3YrSrcYQnvV3

Comment: If I’m u understanding it correct.. you want to resize UIPageViewController in ScrollView based on its content size. Right?

Comment: Hi @RyanCyrus thanks for your reply. I made an image to better clarify what I want to get [https://imagebin.ca/v/3YrSrcYQnvV3](https://imagebin.ca/v/3YrSrcYQnvV3)

Comment: @mulp did you solve this?

Comment: @hasan83 yes, but I used a table view. The pager is part of the table view header and when an item is tapped, I reload the main section using a transition that simulate the push or pop, based on the direction.

Comment: @mulp can you explain a bit more how you did accomplish this? I have a UITableView, with a header, and i have inside the first cell a UIPageViewController. This pageViewController has different childs and depeding of each child i resize the height of the uitableview cell but i have some issues, its the same as you?

Comment: @Godfather I managed it to work without using UIPageViewController. When I switched on the different section I changed the datasource loading a different table, while keeping the table header the same. In this way I don't have to deal with height changes which was actually the main problem.

Comment: https://github.com/maheshmobile/DynamicHeightPageViewController